# How can I get the top 3000 YouTube Channels sorted by videoView from YouTube Search api?

Tags: curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of top 3000 English YouTube channels in US and ordered by video views. I have tried the following curl command:

```
curl -G "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search" \
-d part="snippet" \
-d type="channel" \
-d maxResults=50 \
-d order="videoCount" \
-d regionCode="US" \
-d relevanceLanguage="en" \
-d key="[api-key]" > youtube_api_sample1_50.txt
```

However, the result is not exactly as I expected. First, I didn't find the statistics such as "video views" and "video counts" in the response. Second, there are still other languages showing up in the result even though after my filters on "en" and "US". Third, the "pageToken" only goes to 10 pages which can only give me 500 maximum result.

As I mentioned in the beginning, is there a way I can get the top 3000 YouTube channel list from the current search api?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong "`part`" parameter. If you want to get view counts use the ["**`statistics`**"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part) instead of `snippet.`

Comment: I have tried "part='statistics' ". It returns error 400 Unknown parameter.. What did I miss?..

Comment: It's giving error if we use statistics
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.part",
                "reason": "unknownPart",
                "message": "statistics",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "part"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "statistics"
    }
}